# I want to fetch date in a given format from database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to fetch date in this format example "20 Aug 2019" and description of 200 words from the database so I am using this:-

```
public function wsUserActivity(){
    $request = Input::all();
    //try {
        //$user_id = $request['user_id'];
        $no=isset($request['page_number'])?$request['page_number']:0;
        $nos=isset($request['count'])?$request['count']:10;
        $skp=$no*$nos;

        $array_json_return = array('status' => '1','msg' => 'Success');

        $u_activity = array();
        $u_articles = DB::table('mst_article')->select('title', DATE_FORMAT('created_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT('updated_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING('description',0,200), 'imported', 'import_url')->where('user_id_fk', $user_id);
        $u_meetup = DB::table('mst_meetup')->select('title', DATE_FORMAT('created_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT('updated_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING('description',0,200), 'imported', 'import_url')->where('user_id_fk', $user_id);
        $u_question = DB::table('mst_question')->select('title', DATE_FORMAT('created_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT('updated_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING('description',0,200), 'imported', 'import_url')->where('user_id_fk', $user_id);
        $u_job = DB::table('mst_job')->select('title', DATE_FORMAT('created_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT('updated_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING('description',0,200), 'imported', 'import_url')->where('user_id_fk', $user_id);
        $u_education = DB::table('mst_education')->select('title', DATE_FORMAT('created_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT('updated_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING('description',0,200), 'imported', 'import_url')->where('user_id_fk', $user_id);
        $u_activity= DB::table('mst_event')->select('title', DATE_FORMAT('created_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT('updated_at', "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING('description',0,200), 'imported', 'import_url')->where('user_id_fk', $user_id)->union($u_articles)->union($u_meetup)->union($u_question)->union($u_job)->union($u_education)->latest()->get();


        $array_json_return['u_activity'] = $u_activity;

    /*} catch (\Exception $e) {
        $array_json_return = $this->api_default_fail_response(__function__, $e);
    }*/

    echo json_encode($array_json_return);
}
```

But it is giving this error:

> date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

Now it is giving this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'order clause' (SQL: (select `title`, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING(description,0,200), `imported`, `import_url` from `p1036_mst_event` where `user_id_fk` is null) union (select `title`, DATE_FORMAT("created_at", "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING(description,0,200), `imported`, `import_url` from `p1036_mst_article` where `user_id_fk` is null) union (select `title`, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING(description,0,200), `imported`, `import_url` from `p1036_mst_meetup` where `user_id_fk` is null) union (select `title`, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING(description,0,200), `imported`, `import_url` from `p1036_mst_question` where `user_id_fk` is null) union (select `title`, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING(description,0,200), `imported`, `import_url` from `p1036_mst_job` where `user_id_fk` is null) union (select `title`, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d-%b-%Y"), SUBSTRING(description,0,200), `imported`, `import_url` from `p1036_mst_education` where `user_id_fk` is null) order by `created_at` desc)

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: Now it is giving this error:-

Comment: Check my answer and first run this query only and return. If it works, then implement it to rest query.

Comment: I updated my answer. use " as created_at " example: \DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%b-%Y") as created_at'

Answer (score 1):

Would you please check it-

```
$user_id = $request['user_id'];
$u_articles = DB::table('mst_article')
    ->select('title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), DB::Raw('SUBSTRING(description, 1, 200) as description'), 'imported', 'import_url')
    ->where('user_id_fk', $user_id)
    ->get();
dd($u_articles);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of following:**

```
->select('title', DATE_FORMAT('created_at', "%d-%b-%Y"),
```

**Use:**

```
->select('title', \DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%b-%Y") as created_at'),
```

**Explanation:**

You are using DATE_FORMAT and PHP assumes that you are using PHP method Date_Format instead of mysql DATE_FORMAT method. Use DB::raw method and write mysql code in DB::raw method to get date in desired format.